# RLang: accessing list items via chaining and map (purrr)

Tags: r, purrr, method-chaining

I'm trying R again after a few years, much more used to Python dicts or Kotlin maps or JS objects. I am simply trying the access the value of key-value pairs after using some chaining methods. Unfortunately the normal accessors `$` and `[[` are not returning the expected values, or throwing errors.

Any idea how to simply get a list of the correct state names ("Alabama", "California", "Arizona") from my sample code? Thank you.

```
states_list <- list("AL"="Alabama", "AK"="Alaska", "AZ"="Arizona", "CA"="California")  # (etc)
states_hash <- hash("AL"="Alabama", "AK"="Alaska", "AZ"="Arizona", "CA"="California")  # (etc)

"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% map(~ states_list$.x)  # NULL 
"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% map(~ states_list[.x]) # k-v pairs, not just the values

"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% map(~ states_hash$.x)  # NULL 
"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% map(~ has.key(.x, states_hash)) # AL:TRUE CA:TRUE AZ:TRUE 
"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% map(~ states_hash[.x]) # k-v pairs, not just the values

"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% map(~ states_list[[.x]]) # error - "recursive indexing failed at level 2"
"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% map(~ states_hash[[.x]]) # error - "wrong arguments for subsetting an environment"

"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% states_list[[.x]] # error - "object '.x' not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is really the `str_split` step. Note that `str_split` will return a list, rather than a vector. (It does this because you can pass multiple strings to the function at once and it will keep all the results separated in the list.) So when you `map` over that list, you are just mapping over the single list, not each of three elements in the vector in the list. A somewhat clumsy way to change that is

```
"AL-CA-AZ" %>% {str_split(., "-")[[1]]} %>% map(~states_list[[.x]])
```

You can clean it up a bit with `purrr:pluck`

```
"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% pluck(1) %>% map(~states_list %>% pluck(.x))
```

Or just do direct indexing for the last step

```
"AL-CA-AZ" %>% str_split("-") %>% pluck(1) %>% {states_list[.]}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Imagine the list values are numbers, not strings, and I want to SUM() at the end. I currently get the error `invalid 'type' (list) of argument`... how can I convert the result into a vector (or any data type than can be summed)? Also, can you explain what the curly brackets do, or refer me to some documentation?

Comment: If you are expecting numbers, use `map_dbl` to get a numeric vector rather than the generic `map`. Curly braces just create a code block. They can effect to way the pipe behaves. See https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Again, thank you. I tried submitting a question with the minimum overhead for easiest reproducibility. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work inside a dataframe `mutate()`, as pluck() throws `must be size 133650 or 1, not 3` . Same with the first example, with the [[1]]. If I skip the pluck() and just do map(~states_list[[.x]]) it throws `recursive indexing failed at level 2`

Comment: If it's in a data.frame it sounds like you probably should be doing some type of join instead. It would be better to make a new question that more closely represents what you are trying to do.